# Changing column name - replace the prefix

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have the dataframe below:

```
>colnames(df)

>[1] "0939.HK.Open"     "0939.HK.High"     "0939.HK.Low"      "0939.HK.Close"    "0939.HK.Volume"   "0939.HK.Adjusted"
```

Wondering if I can replace column name with a defined symbol?

```
>symbol<-'0123.KI'
```

And what I would like to obtain is:

```
>[1] "0123.KI.Open" "0123.KI.High" "0123.KI.Low" "0123.KI.Close" "0123.KI.Volume" "0123.KI.Adjusted"
```

Thank you so much guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
colnames(df) <- paste0(symbol, ".", tools::file_ext(colnames(df)))
```

As the column names look like a filename, I am taking the extension - *file_ext*, then adding the *symbol* using *paste0*.

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
symbol <- '0123.KI'
colnames(df) <- gsub("0939.HK", symbol, colnames(df), fixed=TRUE)
```